# In Postgres, how to preserve newline character in COPY TO command?

Tags: postgresql

One of the column of my table contains string with '\n'.

```
postgres=# select * from stringtest ;

 id |    inputstr

----+-----------------

  1 | Name : NOC\r   +

    | \r             +

    | Detail : Detail

(1 row)
```

But when I retrieve same table with COPY TO, new line character is getting escaped

```
postgres=# COPY (select * from stringtest) TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER E'\t' ;

1       Name : NOC\r\n\r\nDetail : Detail
```

How can I make COPY TO command to replace '\n' with new line ??

Expected output :

```
postgres=# COPY (select * from stringtest) TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER E'\t' ;

1       Name : NOC\r
        \r
        Detail : Detail
```

How to achieve this ??

Comment: Not really, but the purpose of COPY default format is to be interpreted as input by another COPY, not to be generically reusable. Maybe the CSV format would be closer to your pupose.